# Shrink part of disk to a new virtual disk

Tags: ext4, dd, gparted

I have a Linux system (Debian 11) on a disk. Partition is 100GB, system only needs 10GB of data.

If I get all the disk (dd) and use it for as a disk of a virutual system (qemu, kvm) all is fine.

How can I get only 10GB (or a bit more) of the disk and also make it work??
Thats possible?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's not in use, you can shrink the size of an ext4 filesystem. If you do that, then shrink the partition to fit it, and then only copy the relevant amount of storage via `dd`, you get a smaller working image.

For what it's worth you could just as well also just recreate the partitions (there's probably going to be a separate UEFI system partition, at least) as needed, just copy over the *files* (using boring `cp -a -r`), fix the entries in the target's /etc/default/grub to point to the UUIDs of the new partitions, reinstall the bootloader, and be all set.